# PHPicker Pick Video SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to display a picker where users can pick a Photo or a Video. I can only find explanations on how to respond to users picking a Photo. I'm not too familiar with UIKit so can someone help me out?

This is my picker function:

```
func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult]) {
       picker.dismiss(animated: true)
        
       guard let provider = results.first?.itemProvider else {return} 
    
       if provider.canLoadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) {
           provider.loadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) { image, _ in
               self.parent.image = image as? UIImage
           }
       }
}
```

Comment: Did you solve this yet?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71374994/swift-how-to-handle-video-and-photo-results-from-a-phpicker for solution